# After upgrading to version 5.0, error in makemigrations with no changes made

Tags: django-migrations

After upgrading to version 5 from 3.2.8, running makemigration, without any changes, gives following error:

> assert field_name not in relations_to_remote_model[model_key]

which comes from line 453 in
`\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\state.py`

The field is a `ManyToMany` field going through a "through" table using "through_fields."

It checks to see if a "field_name not in relations_to_remote_model[model_key]" but it is not

Any insight would be appreciated.

I've tried deleting the fields from the tables in models.py and still same error.

Only by commenting out this check am I able to makemigrations.